# Unable to share a file in Team Drive with anyone with link and for people outside organization

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I would like to use Google Drive API to share a file with anyone that has the link to view the file.

However, i failed with error 403,   even if I used admin account

```
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file."
```

I tried using the API Explorer  but still failed.

Followings are my parameters, please help

```
fileID:"xxxxxxx"

Request Body
{
  "role": "reader",
  "type": "anyone"
}
```

And the response

```
Response
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientFilePermissions",
    "message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file."
 }
}
```

Please check and help.

Thanks

Comment: What is the role of the user requesting? I've tried creating one and here is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZkdZ.png), the user requesting has full permission of team drive.

Comment: Hi there, I the role of user requesting is admin(full permission). I also did what you have done successfully. The only problem here is : If the request body type is "anyone" then it will throws the error.

Comment: AFAIK, setting it to anyone is not supported. There is only 2 way to access/share a file in team drive, become a member or specifically share it to a user. You can also check this documentation about [member and file access](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-teamdrives#direct-access) which explain how access control behaves in team drives.

Comment: Hi there, I am able to fix the problem. In fact you can still share file to anyone to access from outside with the link. Just delete the permission that allow reader in the same domain, then create a permission for reader with type:"anyone". It works for me.